# Testing a void service method with mocked repository in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-test

My Spring Boot application provides the following service which increments a counter on the `User` entity and persists it to the database.

```java
@Service
public class MyService {
    
    @Autowired
    UserRepo userRepo;
    
    public void incrementLoginFailures(String email) throws UserNotFoundException {
        final User user = userRepo.findByEmail(email).orElseThrow(UserNotFoundException::new);
        user.incrementLoginFailures();
        userRepo.save(user);
    }
}
```

Now I'd like to write a JUnit 5 test for this, preferrably mocking the respository but I guess I have some trouble understanding the concept of mocking here.

As you can see, the service method `incrementLoginFailures()` does not return anything so I don't know how I could check that the login counter on the `User` entity was actually incremented. Do I need to write an integration test for this kind of check which actually spins up a database?

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class UserServiceTest {

  @InjectMocks
  private UserService userService;

  @Mock
  private UserRepo userRepo;

  @Test
  public void shouldIncrement() {
    userService.incrementLoginFailures("foo@bar.com");
    Assertions.assertEquals(1, xyz);  // from what source would xyz come from?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test method before calling `userService.incrementLoginFailures("foo@bar.com");`
you will need to mock the return values of the methods called on userRepo something like below:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class UserServiceTest {

  @InjectMocks
  private UserService userService;

  @Mock
  private UserRepo userRepo;

  @Test
  public void shouldIncrement() {
    User user = new User();//please initialize as per your requirement
    when(userRepo.findByEmail("foo@bar.com")).thenReturn(user);
    userService.incrementLoginFailures("foo@bar.com");//this method will make changes to the user object
    Assertions.assertEquals(1, user.getLoginFailures());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend returning the user object from the method to help with testing. To setup mock repository behavior, use `Mockito.when` and return a new user POJO. Then assert the login failure count is 1 on the returned object.

Answer (score 1):

You should only test your own code and in unit test the code for that unit. So not for example if Spring data repository `save()` works. You can test it but you should trust that it works.

If done correct you should have a unit test that asserts that `user.incrementLoginFailures()` works as it should.

```
// Unit test for the user
@Test
public void shouldIncrement() {
    User user = new User();
    // In here when you have just initialized user you might know that 
    // the initial count is zero but it is overall better to assert 
    // the logic for any value / case
    int originalLoginFailures = user.getLoginFailures();
    user.incrementLoginFailures();
    assertEquals(originalLoginFailures + 1, user.getLoginFailures());
 }
```

That is actually what you need to know in addition that the data is saved to the database.

So you might have a unit test for `UserService` (or is it MyService?)  that asserts that `userIncrementLoginFailures()` and `userRepo.save()` is called for user with email **foo@bar.com** when `userService.incrementLoginFailures("foo@bar.com")` is called.

That would be done with `verify`, like:

```
@InjectMocks
private MyService userService;
@Mock
private UserRepo userRepo;
@Mock
private User user; 

@Test
public void shouldIncrementAndSave() throws UserNotFoundException {
    when(userRepo.findByEmail("foo@bar.com")).thenReturn(Optional.of(user));
    userService.incrementLoginFailures("foo@bar.com");
    verify(user).incrementLoginFailures();
    verify(userRepo).save(user);
}
```

**You could** test that `user.incrementLoginFailures()` works in here also, but because you tested it in your *user unit test* it is not necessarily needed but is a redundant test and tests a logic that does not belong to unit tested, namely `UserService`.